# Передать значения отмеченных checkbox в url в виде get параметра

Tags: php, javascript

Как передать значения отмеченных checkbox в url в виде get параметра?
В итоге хочу получить примерно такой url: `www.test.ru/?r=1&r=2`.
Уточню нужно без кнопки submit.

Comment: а что такое `r` и что такое `1` и `2`?

Comment: @Diskyp Это значения input  value.
мой инпут <input id="cbx<?= $region['region_id'] ?>" class="invisible" type="checkbox" name="r[]" value="<?= $region['region_id'] ?>" >
 Попробую чуть подробнее: я делаю фильтр. у меня url вида
test.ru/?ur&agreed мне к текущему url нужно добавить отмеченные значения чекбоксов name="r"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let objectWithCheckboxes={},
withParams=!!location.search,
siteHref=location.href
$('input').change(e=>{
 let el=e.target,
  jq=$(el)
  if(jq.is(':checked')) objectWithCheckboxes[el.id]=el.name
  else delete objectWithCheckboxes[el.id]
  let res=[]
  for(let k in objectWithCheckboxes) res.push(objectWithCheckboxes[k]+'='+k)
  res=res.length?(withParams?'&':'?')+res.join('&'):''
  //window.history.replaceState('','',siteHref+res)
  //^ эта строчка заменяет URL в браузере без перезагрузки страницы
  console.log(siteHref+res)
  //^ а это для теста
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx1" name="r[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx2" name="r[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx3" name="r[]">
```

В итоге в php массиве `$_GET['r']` будут находиться id елементов, на которых поставили флажок.

Comment: вставляю ваш код, мне пишет SyntaxError: redeclaration of let cbxs

Comment: @ganjo888 у вас, видимо, уже есть переменная `cbxs`, сейчас заменю её на что-нибудь другое.

Comment: @ganjo888 так лучше?

Comment: ошибка та же, значит дело не в дубли переменной(

Comment: сейчас все проверю

Comment: получилось, но существующий url затирается тоесть, изначально у меня url такой test.ru/?ur&agreed , как можно подствить в текущий url эти get параметры? Хотелось бы такой url  test.ru/?ur&agreed&r[]=cbx2&r[]=cbx3

Comment: @ganjo888 да, я вот прям сейчас взялся проверять скрипт у себя на сервере и уже внёс эти улучшения.

Comment: @ganjo888 теперь изначальный адрес сайта сохраняется отдельно.

Comment: очень благодарен за ваш труд, небольшая загвоздка смотрите:
если url был изначально таким test.ru/?&r[]=1 то  всё хорошо, но если url был таким test.ru/?c=1 то он прописывает r[]=54 и url становится таким test.ru/?c=1?r[]=54 , и у меня мой скрипт не срабатывает

Comment: @ganjo888 уххх, чёртовы баги, сколькож их ещё? Сделал проверку на наличие других get параметров в url, чтобы вставлять & вместо ?

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: @ganjo888 пожалуйста, любезный. Буду рад, если вы ещё на треугольник вверх нажмёте)

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас нет кнопки "submit" то вы должны к чему то привязывать формирование и отправку запроса на сервер. Очевидней всего привязываться к событию клик по чекбоксу. Однако нужно понимать что каждый клик по каждому чекбоксу будет генерировать запрос на сервер с значениями выделенных чекбоксов. Нужна ли серверу такая нагрузка?

в примере строку   `console.log(target.toString())` нужно заменить на тот механизм который отправит данные на сервер. Например `fetch(target)`

```js
const sendCkecked = () => {
  const target = new URL('http://www.test.ru/');
  const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].checked) target.searchParams.set('r' + i, boxes[i].value)
  }
  console.log(target.toString()); // для демонстрации результата
  // fetch(target); // для отправки данных на сервер
}

const blockEvent = event => event.stopPropagation();
```

```html
<fieldset onClick="sendCkecked()">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="scales" class="checkbox"
               value="1" />
        <label for="scales" onClick="blockEvent(event)">1</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="horns" class="checkbox"
               value="2" />
        <label for="horns" onClick="blockEvent(event)">2</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="claws" class="checkbox"
               value="3" />
        <label for="claws" onClick="blockEvent(event)">3</label>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Вообще не обязательно делать запросы на сервер для формирования нового URL.

Comment: А их никто и не делает. Просто я так подозреваю что цель это всего мероприятия передавать на сервак выбраные чекбоксы. И в конце каждой выполнения обработчика onClick нужно отправлять запрос на сервер

Comment: А, ну я думал по-другому. Что автор хочет запомнить выбранные пользователем чекбоксы, и чтобы при переходе по сгенерированной в адресной строке ссылке, некий php скрипт бы затем сам эти чекбоксы прокликал в зависимости от GET параметров.

Comment: @Diskyp да вы правы, именно так и хочу сделать

Comment: @ganjo888 дак вы ответьте на мой вопрос, который я уже почти час назад задал, я вам всё оформлю.